# How to check whether all elements of a JSON array start with a specific string?

Tags: java, json, junit

The input data looks as follows.

```
[
  { 
    "mahKey": "mahString.yolo",
    "mahValue": "0"
  },
  {
    "mahKey": "notMahString.crymeariver",
    "mahValue": "1"
  },
  {
    "mahKey": "mahSTring.omg",
    "mahValue": "2"
  }
]
```

So I have this.

```
resultActions
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", isA(ArrayList.class)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[mahKey]", Matchers.everyItem(Matchers.startsWith("mahString"))));
```

The array after `$.[mahKey]` looks like this.

```
[
  "mahString.yolo",
  "notMahString.crymeariver",
  "mahSTring.omg"
]
```

However, I get the following error:

```
com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Could not parse token starting at position 3. Expected ?, ', 0-9, *
```

How to check whether all elements of a JSON array start with a specific string in JUnit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

**`"$.*.mahKey"`**

So the syntax would look like:

```
 .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
 .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", isA(ArrayList.class)))
 .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*.mahKey", Matchers.everyItem(Matchers.startsWith("mahString"))));
```

[Tested here](http://jsonpath.com/), it retrieved the elements correctly:

[image]

Comment: Hope to be correct this time, if not, I shoot myself in the face

Comment: You were correct with `$.*.mahKey` (without `[]`) but I don't understand why :) With `$.*.[mahKey]` it doesn't work as well :D At https://jsonpath.com/ I get same result with my initial `$.[mahKey]`.

Comment: *cleaning the gun*

Comment: Well you helped me to solve it so take the points and put away the gun.

Comment: @TonyStark well , it was you who fixed this in reality. I will shoot myself in the leg, it's the fair thing to do.

Comment: Too bad I can't upvote you again for the humour.

Comment: this jsonpath expressions are really wierdo. `$..mahKey` also seem to work. what the heck. Even worse,  `$..[mahKey]` also "works". And `$..*.mahKey` too!  This is worse than a CORBA system written in javascript